# Logic to identify new line item for current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to spot new line items appearing in my data set. So for example I have the following table structure.

The logic needs to identify if the line item is new since the previous billedmonth

TableA

[image: Table Structure]

So if I was to write it in English.

Select IF 'CLI' & 'Description' & 'UnitCost' doesn't exist for BilledMonth -1

I have managed to create a join showing if it exists for the previous billing month.

But I am really struggling with the negative logic (i.e. the line item is new for this month)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.CLI, t.Description 
FROM yourTable t
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
ON t.CLI = t2.CLI
AND t.Description = t2.Description
AND t.UnitCost = t2.UnitCost
AND t.BilledMonth - 1 = t2.BilledMonth
WHERE t2.CLI is null
```

Comment: use one of the join columns for null checking

Comment: It's the case, so indeed the extra comment was not mandatory, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think sql server supports analytic functions, so something like this should work:

```
select  CLI, Description, UnitCost, billedMonth
from (
    select  CLI, Description, UnitCost, billedMonth
        count(*) over (partition by CLI, Description, UnitCost order by billedMonth) cnt
    from mytable
) where cnt = 1
```

Iff this works it is very likely to be way more efficient and faster than a join based select statement.